# Software for marketing clip

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video, clipping-mask

Recently I saw a lot of marketing clips built like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72snZctFFtA).

Mostly I'm talking about the words that jumps and become vertical/horizontal etc. (I'm not talking about the pictures, only the words)

I thought that it's probably complicated, but I saw it a lot so I thought perhaps there is some easy tool for that.

Am I right?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of videos are a basic **Motion Graphics Video**.

Mainly done in [After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html), which is a "Video Composite" program.

A free option is [HitFilm Express](https://hitfilm.com/express).

The also can be done in [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) (free) (or any payed 3D program) using the correct materials (usually a self iluminated one without making it a lightsource)

They also can be done in [Flash or Adobe animate](http://www.adobe.com/products/animate.html). But in that case you might not have the motion blur. (But you can fake it)

A Flash like program is [Synfig Studio](http://www.synfig.org/) (free)

And you also can use a 2D animation program like [Anime Studio](http://my.smithmicro.com/anime-studio-2D-animation-software.html).

And for simpe things, that can be rendered directly on a web page there is [Express Animate](http://www.nchsoftware.com/animation/index.html).

The point of all this programs is that use an "In Between" logic, this is that you define an initial place, size and rotation, and then you define a second point in time with a diferent place, size and rotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In your opinion -  Does this videos are easy to made as I thought? (for rookie designer) (easy = 1-3 hours work)

Comment: Will be easier as you progress... :oP